# Flutter ListView to do a http request as the list scrolls to 70% of the viewport height

Tags: flutter

How do I make a ListView do http requests when it has scrolled every 70% of the viewport?

As I scroll the list, the ListView should make consecutive http requests to fetch data from the api as soon as it reaches a certain height in the scrollable viewport.

Comment: Use `ListView.builder`

Comment: Yes I am using ListView.builder. But how to call an async method after a certain amount of scroll? Is there any controller or method which can be used?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking for asnwer, its possible to use FutureBuilder inside ListView.builder, it work's with async source of data.
For example you could read next article about it [here](https://medium.com/saugo360/flutter-creating-a-listview-that-loads-one-page-at-a-time-c5c91b6fabd3)